# Encoder decoder Conc behavior Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

When trying to implement, the paper generative concatenative network (Lipton et al., 2015), which is bascally concatenate the hidden state output from a LSTM with the decoder input to feed the decoder stage i get the folling error:

"node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'"

```py
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense
from keras.models import Model
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

encoder_input = Input(shape=(46, 21), dtype='float32', name='encoder_input')

# Encoder stage
_, h_s, c_s = LSTM(256,
                   return_sequences=True,
                   return_state=True,
                   dropout=0.0,
                   recurrent_dropout=0.0)(encoder_input)
encoder_states = [h_s, c_s]

decoder_input = Input(shape=(46, 21), name='decoder_input')

conc = True
if conc:
    # Reshape tensor to dimensions -1, 46, 21
    h_s_s = tf.reshape(h_s, (-1, 46, 21))
    x = keras.layers.concatenate([h_s_s, decoder_input])
else:
    x = decoder_input

# Decoder stage
decoder_lstm = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True,
                    dropout=0.0,
                    recurrent_dropout=0.0)
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(x,
                                     initial_state=encoder_states)

# FC layer
main_output = Dense(21, activation='sigmoid', name='main_output')(decoder_outputs)

model = Model(inputs=[encoder_input, decoder_input], outputs=[main_output])
```

I expected the object model to be a  but when creating the object the error is:

"node = layer._inbound_nodes[node_index]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_inbound_nodes'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
h_s_s = tf.reshape(h_s, (-1, 46, 21))
```

You cannot apply TF or backend operations directly in Keras tensors, you need to wrap them in a Lambda layer, but there is already a Layer for reshaping:

```
from keras.layers import Reshape

h_s_s = Reshape((46, 21))(h_s)
```

This will produce another error (`ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged`), and you have to fix it as the reshape dimensions are not right for the layer output. Only the OP knows the right values.

Comment: Thank you Matias for the Insight. By using Reshape with RepeatVector i got h_s_s  to be a tensor with dimentions [?, 46, 256] <tf.Tensor 'reshape_1/Reshape:0' shape=(?, 46, 256) dtype=float32> with that taken into account everything works fine.